# Google maps Javascript API usage statistics does not show

Tags: google-maps, geocoding, google-maps-api

I am currently using the google [Geocoder service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#Geocoder) from the Google Maps JavaScript API in a few applications.

For months I was receiving usage statistics in my API manager, but for the last 2 months it has gone dark [usage screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DC4eI.jpg).

I know that the service is still working, and I know that we are receiving around 500 -1000 geocode requests per day across 3 apps... But as we add geocoding functionality to more maps, or if we hit a peak day (we have one or two per year) I am worried that I will come close to my 25,000/day limit.

Anyone know why I lost my usage stats? I have tried the "send feedback" form... This error did occur around the time that I moved my API key from my personal gmail account to our organizations account.